# Making long labels visible in a legend

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

How do I handle map legend with tens of classes using QGIS? I searched for instructional videos and previous post relating to the question but could not find any helpful material. The legend text in the map below are partly invisible, I would like to have all the legend text visible.

[image]

N.B: I thought of having the legend part as a second page on the print composer   but on importing the map, the legend part was not printed.

Comment: unasked-for review: that map is...difficult to read, to say the least. it sems you have chosen *random colors*, and I'd say that is a mistake. it will be hard to differ between similar colors, and it's overcrowded with colors. take your time and try to group your entries further; use blue for *alluvial* and symbol fills for different grain sizes or sth., have an addidional symbol fill for *Crystalline Acid Rock* maybe to be used on top of the colors, and so on. that way, the legend will get more structured and the label text will shorten. it gets a little trickier, though ,)

Comment: @ThingumaBob, thanks for the suggestion. I agree the map is quite rough, i had to  georeference a scanned map from [FAO](https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ESDB_Archive/EuDASM/Africa/maps/afr_ngsm.htm) thereafter i created a new spatial layer ,adding features as polygons. Have you any idea how i could improve the results of the georeferenced map?

Comment: If you want more extensive help improving the readability of your map, I suggest posting a new question with the `cartography` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find *word wrap* option for labels in a legend, but QGIS has `Wrap text on` option in "Legend Panel -> Main Properties".

[image]

You can use it in that way:

1. Open "Layer Properties -> Style"
2. Add a character where you want to split text in "Legend" column. (As an example, I added '#')

[image]

3. In Composer, enter the character (# for example) as `Wrap text on` value.

[image]