# Wrapping legend text in QGIS MapComposer at character count

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I want to wrap legend text after a certain amount of characters. Is there an automatic way to do that?

I don't want to enter a character (e.g. *) for each line as described in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158295/getting-legend-label-on-multiple-lines-in-qgis), that is too much work...

[image]

Edit: I tried to use an expression, but the button is greyed out...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use an expression string for your labels:

[image]

```
with_variable( 'column',37,
   if(length(@symbol_label) > @column,
      regexp_replace(left(@symbol_label,@column),'(.+)([\\s,;\\.])([^\\s,;\\.]+)$','\\1\\2\n\\3') + substr(@symbol_label,@column+1),@symbol_label))
```

Without expression string:
[image]

With expression string:
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. do you have an idea why the epsilon-button is greyed out in my case?

Comment: You have to select the layer in the legend dialog like in my case.

Comment: I did. But it is a raster layer and you have a vector layer. And I am using the styles of a qml-file. Maybe that is why? I edited my question and added another screenshot.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That‘s totally different... sorry, didn‘t look close enough.

Comment: I guess it's not possible at the moment. You could post a change request in Github.

Comment: Okay, thank you Christoph.

Answer (score 3):

Since QGIS 2.4 you can use [`wordwrap`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#wordwrap) function.

For 50 characters it would be like this:

```sql
wordwrap(@symbol_label, 50)
```

Comment: This is a solution for some projects, but to me, using qGIS 3.26-3.28, the `wordwrap`-expression does not work reliably for an atlas (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51465). However, adding a special character to the legend, as shown in the initial post seems to be more reliable (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158295/getting-legend-label-on-multiple-lines-in-qgis, and here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297354/making-long-labels-visible-in-a-legend)