# Dynamic breaks of legend text in QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, dynamic

I want to wrap legend text after a certain amount of characters depending on the width (variable) of the legend item.

I already tried the answer given at [Wrapping legend text in QGIS MapComposer at character count](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374167/wrapping-legend-text-in-qgis-mapcomposer-at-character-count). This solution is not working well for me. Is there a way to apply a expression to all layers ?

I want to have a automatic legend text for my atlas composition without having to manually wrap text legend.

Exemple 1 of atlas page

[image]

Exemple 2 of atlas page

[image]

Legend text of all layers

[image]

When using the expression wordwrap it seems to work at first but then QGIS goes suddenly very slow. The text legend seems to be constantly loading beetween wrapped and unwrapped mode.

Picture of wrapped text with the expression

[image]

Picture of unwrapped text with the same expression, one second later

[image]

[Data and Project links](https://we.tl/t-O4iRV13Ke8)

Comment: Why didn't the linked answer work?

Comment: To be honest i don't really know : it works for some layers and it does not for others. I don't really understand how the expression works either.
It seems also that applying this expression to all my layers make the map composer very slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a much simpler expression you can try.

Using the same "Expression button".

You can use:

> wordwrap(@symbol_label, 5)

With 5 here representing the number of characters it should wrap after.

[image]

Comment: very elegant solution!

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Comment: Hi @FlorianMarlière if the answer has solved your issue please mark it as correct using the green tick near the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @HeikkiVesanto's solution: Go to `Project / Properties / Variables`, create a new variable called `project_wrap` and insert the expression there.

The advantage is the possibility to automatically update the length of the lines of all layers at once in the legend. Use the variable in the print composer (instead of the whole expression): paste `eval(@project_wrap)`. If you then change the variable definition (change no. of characters), the line-length automatically changes at once for **all** lines defined with this variable. Not need to manually tweek each line separately.

Updating of the legend takes a while. Simply open the expression button and close immediately, then the legends updates.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The concept works fine but when i do this, QGIS suddenly goes very slow and the legend seems to constantly be loading, switching beetween wrapped text and unwrapped text. I'll edit the post to show what i mean.

Comment: I guess best would be if you could share the project (with data) for testing. Save project, close QGIS an reopen project does not help?

Comment: Reopening QGIS does not help. I tried to use this expression in a simple map composer (no atlas) and it worked great. So the issue seems to come frome the Atlas Composer ?

Comment: Might be. From far, it's difficult to say. What QGIS version?

Comment: 3.20.2-Odense
Uptated the data and project if you want to try it. Eitherway thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Which of the projects? Which layout?

Comment: The project Template SHP juillet 2021" and for the layouts, it will be automatically updated by the atlas composer. All layers are used in different page of the atlas composer.

Comment: For me, it seems to work with your project, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/42SrL.png - But only in this layout; the other two have no legend and I get an error saying `No matching atlas features found!`. I'm not sure but I guess the others are raster layers. With rasters, this solution does not seem to work

Comment: Indeed it works with this layout. The other two are the ones where i did an atlas focused on only 1 polygon, and several layers per pages. Maybe for those ones, there is too much data to handle idk. Your error tho should comes from the path of the layer "Site". If you make a new shp and then change the path of the layer "Site" it should works.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the legend in the principal map canvas to avoid this issue ?

Comment: You could try in layer properties / legend, but I'm not sure if it offers such an option

Comment: No option found, just so you know :)

Comment: Probably your prblem indeed has to do with the fact that you're project is quite large. Maybe create a dummy project with just a few simple layers to see if that works. Than at least it's clear where the problem is.